# Error handling for a while loop

Tags: java

I need help with this scenario where I need to find a string from a pagination table wherein each page contains 50 items. My code below works fine, only problem is that when it cannot find the data my while loop sometimes keep running indefinitely and does not fail but sometimes it does! What can I do so that it will always return an error after reaching a number of loops?

```
public int inboxLocateLoan(String expName, String name) throws Throwable {
  //Locate Loan element in SharePoint table
  report.setFailedResult("Loan element is not found");
  int loanRow;
  try {
   boolean loansearch = true;
   while (loansearch) {
    List < WebElement > rowElem = getWebElements(getAEDriver(), "xpath", sRow);
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowElem.size(); i++) {
     String actualLoanName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='onetidDoclibViewTbl0']/tbody[2]/tr[" + i + "]/td[3]")).getText();

     //       String actualLoanNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='onetidDoclibViewTbl0']/tbody[2]/tr["+i+"]/td[5]")).getText();
     loanRow = i;
     if (actualLoanName.equals(expName)) {
      loansearch = false;
      return loanRow;
     }
     if (actualLoanName.equals(name)) {

      click(getAEDriver(), "xpath", "//*[@class='ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt-selected']", "Refresh");


      loansearch = true;
     } else {
      if (i == 50) {
       click(getAEDriver(), "xpath", "//*[@id='pagingWPQ2next']/a", "Next Page");
      } else {
       loansearch = true;
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you; so you please spend the few minutes it takes to properly format/indent your code input; instead of dropping such a **mess** on us. Would you dare to show such code to a peer when asking for help? But with us, it is ok?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the romElem outside the `for`, and then use it to toggle your flag. If you reached your max rowElemen and you didn't find what you were looking for, it is safe then to assume that the value will be false.

Also, what is the purpose of the while? you could remove it completely, it is usually a bad idea to mix a while and a for. I don´t see the point in doing so in this case.